# New users aren't posting their own questions - are we scaring them off?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6624/47620) now has two questions-posted-as-answers from new users. When this happens, we delete the answer but also leave a comment asking the new user to post their own question:

> Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! Unfortunately, your answer does not answer the question. Without wishing to sound harsh, StackExchange is a Q&A site, and not a forum of threaded messages. The reason for this is to aid the search for answers to issues, and provide it in a structured Q&A way. I know that this might seem a pain, but can you repost your question using the Ask Question link at the top of the page? When you repost your new question, please feel free to refer back to this original question using the URL, seeing as it is the reason why you posted in the first place

However, they don't seem to ever re-post their query as a question.

So, my point is, should we:

1. Convert the answer into a comment so that someone can answer them (also via a comment);
2. Leave the answer as is (so that someone can answer them (also via a comment)), or;
3. Continue deleting and leaving the standard comment.

Points 1 and 2 are both against SE policy, and would turn the Q&A format into a forum of threaded messages, so point 3 would be the correct "SE way" of doing things. However, it does also mean that these new users:

1. Don't get any help, and;
2. Seem to get scared off.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or am I worrying too much?

I guess a user with enough rep could (if they know the answer), briefly undelete the answer, leave a comment as to provide a solution, and then re-delete it. However, this is a double edged sword: this wouldn't encourage the new user to post their own question, although it would give them the help that they need. Also, not only does it encourage bad SE etiquette, we probably don't have enough users with sufficient rep to do this.

Another way of looking at it is that, if the new user *really* needs help then they *will* post their own question, and if they don't post one, then they weren't all that desperate, after all.

Comment: Most people posting their first question don't know the rules at SE. I don't think we should bend the rules. Just delete their answer but leave a message to post their own question. We should stick to option 3 IMHO.

Comment: Is it possible to add option "Turn into question" available only to answer's author? - for example only if the answer has been flagged? For example in my case, I am trying to give answers, but so far I did not add any new question. Why...? I plan to do some research before, including searching the knowledge base prior to asking... thus, maybe I am afraid to introduce duplicate, or prefer to remain in comfort zone. (And the last sentence about desperation is true.) Maybe this is just psychology, therefore I propose such shortcut / incentive.

Comment: @octopus8 - Nope, not without a feature request being submitted to SE.Meta (which would be a very good idea). Currently, there's nothing in the UI to do that. There may already be such a request, have a look. I vaguely recall the topic (but not a UI feature request) being discussed, and apparently it was something to do with moderators shouldn't be able to force the user to do something (i.e. write a question for them, when maybe they don't want to). But, hold on, you are saying for the user, and the user only, to do? Then that would be a very good idea.

Comment: Not sure if you've changed how you're handling flags but recently I noticed a lot of my NAA flags are being marked disputed even though they're being deleted straight away, for example: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/how-do-i-calibrate-the-temperature-of-my-hotend/15477#15477

Comment: @PeterJ Could be caused by the system, mods get a review (summary) of flags, but with very little content (probably caused by SO as they get hundreds of flags per day), sometimes it is not obvious from that interface if the flag should be honored or not, in such cases I go to the question and do the modding, this may surpass the flag and mark it as dispute? It certainly is not intentional! Your (and others') moderation flagging is highly appreciated!